# border-image bitmap not properly tiling

Tags: css

I am having trouble properly tiling a border image from a 2x2 bitmap.

The 2x2 bitmap ('hr.gif') looks like this: [image]

Here is the html/css:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  #border {
      border: 2px solid;
      border-image: url(hr.gif) repeat;
      display: table;
  }
</style>
<div id="border"><p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p></div>
```

This is what the border looks like on the page: [image]

And this is how I would like the border to look: [image]

edit: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4ujxpy06/)

Comment: Not sure I understand - Both DIV and P tags are block level elements, so if you need to wrap the text, you can do something like `<div><p><span id="border">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</span></p></div>` (And I'd recommend using class for this type of style (Unless you're sure this is a unique style)

Comment: I apologize if the question is unclear. I don't want to "wrap the text." I want to use a custom bitmap .gif as a repeating image for the div border. The above code example gives me the first image; I would like the border to look like the second image (which is a mock-up).

Comment: As far as I see, it's impossible to make this dash repeat. However, you could create some square with texture for the border and use that. There are few examples https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to use a 6x6 bitmap in order to fill in the border gaps. Solution below. Here's the new bitmap: [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
#border {
    display: table;
    border-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBgAGAKECAAAAAP///6Ag8KAg8CH5BAEKAAIALAAAAAAGAAYAAAILRGynYCIJ3EFqnQIAOw==") 2 space;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
}
</style>
<div id="border"><p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p></div>
```

Here's what it looks like (notice the edges are not perfect, as the tile is truncated if the width is not even; I don't believe there is a solution to that, but it is a negligible issue): [image]

Comment: In a production environment, I would advise against using the base64 above, as the text representation of the bitmap is more than twice the size of the .gif file (58 bytes vs ~102 bytes, respectively)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to try with border-style property: dotted; ?

Comment: I have tried using `border: 2px dotted;` both with and without the `border-image` property. The former gives me an ugly 4-pixel wide box (https://i.imgur.com/3EvS3P1.gif) while the latter is plagued by the same issue as the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try top change border image syntax to:
`border-image: url(hr.gif) 10 round;`
and play with numbers (I can't get your image so I used it from W3C).

Result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  #border {
      border: 2px solid;
      border-image: url(hr.gif) 10 round;
  }
</style>
<div id="border"><p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p></div>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/svitch/pen/eGxOVx)

Comment: apologies, I understand the image is quite small. Here it is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiHGq.gif

Playing with the numbers in your above example does not have any effect